# What does it mean for a function to be uniquely determined by another function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

In munkres topology, I went through an exercise which asks me to show that a function is uniquely determined by another function.

I wonder, What does this mean? I googled it but No answer!

Here is the problem:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a bit more context.

Comment: @fuglede, Ok, I will add the problem right now.

Comment: @fuglede, you can check now the question again.

Comment: It's asking you prove that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous extensions of $f$, then $g_1=g_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there $g,h$ are function $g,h\colon \bar A\to Y$ with $g|_A=h|_A=f$, then $g=h$. In other words, if you think you have two extensions, you really have only one.